# Запятые. Как правильно?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

*Как важно, что есть те, кто может и знает, чем просветить нас.*

Расставил в этом предложении запятые, не знаю, правильно ли. Можете пояснить правила пунктуации по всем запятым? Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(1) *Как важно, (2)  **что** есть те, (3)  **кто** может и знает, (4) **чем** просветить нас.*

Знаки расставлены верно.

Это сложноподчиненное предложение (СПП) с **последовательным подчинением** трех придаточных:

(1) главное предложение, односоставное, безличное;

(2) придаточное изъяснительное предложение, союз ЧТО;

(3) придаточное местоименно-определительное предложение, союзное слово КТО (местоименная пара ТЕ — КТО);

(4) придаточное изъяснительное предложение, союзное слово ЧЕМ.

**Редактирование** (стилистическая неточность при управлении):

*Как важно, что есть те, кто **может оказать помощь** и (кто) знает, чем просветить нас.*

Глагол "может" не управляет союзным словом ЧЕМ, поэтому нельзя объединить "может и знает". Тогда предложение (3) нужно разделить на два однородных придаточных: запятая между ними не ставится, союзное слово КТО пропущено.

Comment: "Он может чем нас порадовать". Я порой встречаю такие обороты; они разговорные, но тем не менее ведь допустимы, да?

Comment: Я полагаю, что нет. Если такие обороты встречаются, то, возможно, это грамматический сленг, когда намеренно искажают правильную конструкцию (рисуются как бы).

Comment: Скорее всего, в таких случаях "чем" -- это урезанное "чем-то" либо инверсия вопросительного предложения, чтобы подчеркнуть ударение на "чем": *"Он может нас порадовать". -- "Он может **чем** нас порадовать?"* (здесь не выражается сомнение в том, что вообще может порадовать, в отличие от "Чем он может нас порадовать?")

Comment: Чем-то то он может нас порадовать? Здесь ударение явно на первом слове, только именно "чем-то", но не "чем". Если уж дело только в ударении.

Comment: @Nektoid  У Розенталя есть материал с инверсией придаточных http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=137#pp137  Пункт 2.  Например: Уже месяц, как он вернулся с юга (ср.: Он уже месяц как вернулся с юга. По этому  образцу я могу представить такое предложение:  Он чем порадовать нас может? Здесь инверсия очевидна, поэтому семантика и грамматика будут поняты.  Но вот предложение "Он может чем нас порадовать" выглядит как откровенное нарушение грамматики и, скорее всего, именно так будет воспринято большинством пользователей.

Comment: Спасибо за Розенталя, интересно. // В таких случаях ударное слово выделяют, подчёркивая его нестандартное положение: "Он может *чем* нас порадовать?" Но я бы вообще убрал его в конец: "Он может нас порадовать чем?" -- тем самым ярче подчёркивается основной смысловой вес на "чем", чем если бы это слово стояло в начале, как требует грамматика.

Comment: Ну, может,  действительно при явном нарушении грамматики оба этих варианта будут правильно поняты.  Но ударение в них разное (на глагол и на местоимение), поэтому семантические различия есть. В одном случае  вообще хоть чем-то порадовать, а во втором  (местоимение в конце предложения) чем-то конкретным порадовать.  Но все это пока чисто разговорная речь.